# Using PCA to model highly correlated variables

Tags: machine-learning, generalized-linear-model, pca, feature-selection, overfitting

Specifically, [Andrew Ng states](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1wHRAuqZ90) that PCA should be used to speed up algorithms or to visualize data.  He also states that using PCA as a way to prevent overfitting is an incorrect application of PCA.  The logic being that PCA only compares predictor variables with other predictor variables and ignores the response; thus, it's possibly removing information that relates to the response variable and therefore it is a sub-optimal way to prevent overfitting.  He recommends regularization instead.

I have seen PCA recommended as a way to model highly correlated variables, rather than fitting the highly correlated variables themselves.  Is this a correct application of PCA (it seems to me that it would have the same flaws as using it to prevent overfitting)?  If not, what is the best way to correct for model instability caused by correlated predictor variables?

More specifically, if I am fitting a GLM and 2 or more predictor variables are correlated to the point the model is no longer stable; however, there is signal hidden in the correlated predictor variables then what should be my approach?  Some options would be:

- It the variables into a PCA and fit on the output
- Only use one of the correlated variables
- Include the correlated variables and their interaction
- Fit some transform or other linear combination of the variables

I said GLM in this example, though the same issue could arise in a machine learning application (neural nets, SVM, etc) as well.

Comment: "To deal" in what context? In order to achieve what?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you'd use PCA to overcome overfitting. I was always taught that when you performed PCA you retained as many components as there were variables. If I performed a PCA and used it to form predictors in, e.g., a regression I'd still fit the same number of variables with the same amount of variance (just restructured a little to make the components orthogonal). I suppose you could use fewer components than there were variables, but as I suggested I was taught that factor analysis is for variable reduction and PCA for variable restructuring.

Comment: @Ian_Fin It's called "principal component regression": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_regression

Comment: The idea behind PCA is to create new variable that capture most of the information in your features. There are few regression methods based on this principle. As @amoeba has already pointed out, PCR and there is Partial Least Square Regression which is widely used for multicollinear data.  Check them out and maybe one of them is suitable for your case.

Comment: @amoeba fair criticism.  I tried to be more specific.

Comment: Ng's criticism is good.  In this case, though, exactly what do you mean by "model highly correlated variables"?  What is the goal?  What kind of model do you have in mind?

Comment: Please tell us the purpose of "fitting a GLM."  If it is to estimate coefficients of the regressors, then indeed you might have a problem--and it's unlikely to be resolved without collecting appropriate data; but if it's for other purposes, such as to predict or interpolate values, then collinearity is not going to make your model "unstable" at all.

Comment: @whuber Yes, I need stable coefficients of the regressors.  I would think that even if I was only predicting values that unstable coefficients would be troublesome.

Comment: Actually not: the instability occurs only because some regressors can practically replace others in the model.  *What* values get predicted is not unstable. The greater risk lies in the possibility that these regressors are *not* interchangeable, but only appear to be because they *happen* to be nearly collinear in your sample.  When that's the case, predictions from new data can appear to be wildly off. You can check that by keeping track of the Mahalanobis distances between new data and the original sample used to fit the model.